Potential Energy and Potential for magnetic fields
I am bit of a confuse. What i did study in my 12th class is that potential energy and potential is only defined for conservative forces then why do we get to see quantities like magnetic potential energy even though magnetic fields are non-conservative in nature?

Have you asked your 12th grade teacher?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/567339/2451 and links therein.
